# Why is this condition true?

Tags: ruby

Why is the following condition true? I was thinking the equality would apply to both variables but it doesn't. Even if they are surrounded in parentheses.

What is num_1 evaluating to that it is true?

```
num_1 = "2"
num_2 = "1"

if num_1 && num_2 == "1"
    puts "condition met"
end
```

I'm aware the following is what I intended to check:

```
if num_1 == "1" && num_2 == "1"
    puts "condition met"
end
```

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but essentially the answer is that things that aren't `false` or `nil` are true.

Comment: Your `if` conditional first checks if `num_1`, so basically if it has a truthy value set to it (i.e. a value exists for the variable, and is not null or false).

Then (`&&`) the conditional checks `num_2 == "1"`, which in this case is `true`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`num_1`, `num_2`, and `"1"` all evaluate to `true` when used with a boolean operator. In Ruby, all strings are "truthy". As Philip Yoo mentioned, this results in a true expression `num_2 == "1"`, which evaluates to `true`, being `and`ed with `true`, and that is true.

Comment: "`num_1`, `num_2`, and `"1"` all evaluate to `true` when used with a boolean operator" is incorrect. They are truthy, but they are never evaluated to `true`. For example, `"1" && "2"` evaluates to `"2"`, not `true`.

Comment: @Amadan point taken, thanks.